How can I drain standing water from my crawl space?
CONCERN
I own a 21-year-old manufactured home that I bought 4 years ago. It sits on a “permanent” foundation. There are poured concrete walls around the exterior and 40 piers supporting the rest of the house. The crawlspace itself was dug fairly deep. It’s probably around 3 to 4 feet from the ground to the belly wrap/joists as I can squat and move around down there decently enough for a crawlspace. The concern I’m having with water is that there are essentially “pits” between each footer, and this makes it so that water from one pit can’t reach the next one. Because of this about half of the ground in the crawl space has standing water under the vapor barrier when the water table is high and there’s no way for that water to get to the sump pump because the footers are blocking the water unless it gets super high. When I bought the home, the previous owner had a vapor barrier installed along with a dehumidifier, but because of the footers the vapor barrier isn’t perfect, and the dehumidifier isn’t going to do a whole lot when the water table is that high.
OUTSIDE OPINIONS
I had a basement/foundation/crawlspace company come out and give an opinion and their recommendation was to fill in all the crawlspace pits with gravel so that it sits level, dig a trench around the outside of that gravel to allow water to get to the sump pump, then encapsulate the entire thing. My only concern is that this would cost around $40,000. Since this is a manufactured home (albeit on the nicer side) I don’t really feel like it’s worth spending that much money when there’s also still a chance it doesn’t even alleviate the issue. I’m hoping someone here might have some better insight or recommendation to work on a more permanent solution that’s a little more affordable and I can do myself. I might be able to haul some gravel down there, but I might throw a few discs in my back before I'm done haha.
IMMEDIATE TEMPORARY SOLUTION?
In the meantime, I’m going to have a handyman I know patch the belly wrap everywhere we can find just to hopefully mitigate any moisture that’s still going to be down there until I get a more permanent solution. I’ve also considered putting a couple transfer pumps down there in the pits that sit lower in the water table so I can pump the water over to the sump pump. I’m not sure if this will be impactful enough to get enough water out though.
I’ll gladly answer any questions or get any pictures that might help as well. I’ve attached a pic of the footers and “pits” that hopefully gives a little bit of a better picture. The picture posted is where you first get in the crawlspace that stays generally dry, but hopefully gives an idea of what I mean.


First, make sure that the ground surface slopes away from the foundation for at least 10-12 feet on all sides to keep surface water draining away from the foundation. Installing (or ensuring the functioning of) gutters and extending the downspout drains away from the building should also help with that. These are basic steps people often jump right over which can have a considerable effect on the amount of water coming in.
Then, if it's still a problem:
Drop two sump pits (unless you find that one and a trench with perforated pipe is less expensive - I'm guessing two pits will win) outside the foundation deeper than the deepest "pit" inside the foundation. Given the usual length/width of manufactured homes, about 1/4 and 3/4 "lengthways" (at a guess. One might do if the soil is very gravelly, but that usually doesn't go with such water problems.) A full pipe circle around the house (into one pit) would be best, and likely cheaper than working under the house (easy equipment access) but not cheap (except when pouring the foundation wall in the first place, and it's too late for that)
If the ground around the house is generally flat, one on either side at those lengthwise locations. If it generally slopes towards the house from one side, both on that side. Be sure to pump the water far enough away downhill so it does not come back to be pumped in circles.
Of course, do be aware of where your utilities run underground (call Dig-Safe or local equivalent) before digging.

Thanks, this helps a lot. I don't know for sure how the drainage was set up around the house, but I know there's definitely some flaws with it. Currently all of the gutters run straight down into the ground through a black corrugated pipe and I ASSUME they then run out away from the house. It seems like maybe this pipe is also connected to the drain tile which I'm pretty sure isn't correct. But even if it's not, my sump pump currently dumps into one of the gutter french drains and since they're corrugated pipes that are 20 years old, I'm guessing they're completely messed up at the moment.

Continued from previous comment -
Maybe it would just be easier to have a company give an estimate on completely redoing the drain tile and french drains to properly move water away from the house. The land around the home is fairly level but unfortunately most of one direction does go slightly uphill so that might be of concern but of course could be fixed by installing the drains correctly and swapping them to hard pipe instead of corrugated. The drain tile could also be clogged if it does exist and is separate, but I'm not sure how I would be able to check if it's clogged etc.

I guess theoretically if there's drain tile I would be able to see in the sump pit where there's a pipe and possibly snake it from there to see if it's clogged at all even though it won't be perfect.

You can rent a drain (sewer) camera, or hire a plumber with one. Whether that tells you much that's useful is unknown, though.

Another alternative: Hire half a dozen high school kids with ambition and empty pockets and have a ready-mix truck serve a couple yards of suitable gravel to the window. Put the kids in a bucket brigade and get your floor sloped properly to the sump (or at least level to a dry point). If done properly there won't be much gravel left to move once the truck is empty. Your job is just to direct flow.
Now you can put poly sheeting down over the proper grade and pump out what makes it to the sump pail.

The $40,000 price point is not even remotely competitive for the scope of the problem.  It sounds like at worst you need some drain tile installed to improve water movement.  Get another contractor or two to write better quotes.

This definitely helps at least a little bit to know I could maybe get it done for cheaper if it's bad enough haha.
